# Reduce array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I have an array of 100 indices

```
const randomArr = [...Array(100).keys()]
```

How to return 100 array like this

```
[{index: i}, {title: `title${i}`}]
```

where `i` should be index of random array.

Comment: please add a concrete example of the wanted result. and what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you call it "random array"?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const result = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => [
  { index: i }, { title: `title${i}` }
]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that you want a list like

```
[{index: i, title: `title${i}`}]
```

But here goes anyway.

Using [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const randomArr = Array(100).fill(0).map((e, i) =>
  [{ index: i}, {title: `title${i}`}]
);

console.log(randomArr);
```